# Wordpress Custom field from page id

Tags: wordpress, field

So I have the following code.

```
function field_func($atts) {
  global $post;
  $name = $atts['name'];
  if (empty($name)) return;
  return get_post_meta($post->ID, $name, true);
}
add_shortcode('field', 'field_func');
```

This lets me use the shortcode, `[field name='fieldname']` to display the value for that custom field of the current page. However, how would I display the custom field of another post/page on this page with an ID? What code needs to be added so that I can pass `[field name='fieldname']` a second parameter of `id='pageid'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function field_func($atts) {
    global $post;
    $name = $atts['name'];
    $id = $atts['id'];
    ...do whatever with $id and $name...
}
add_shortcode('field', 'field_func');
```

and call with

```
[field name='fieldname' id='pageid']
```

Comment: @Veloncia  Im not sure what your final application for this question is, but if you doing a lot of work with custom fields in Wordpress i would suggest to look into Advanced Custom Fields, its a free plugin that is amazing. the API, documentation and support are all top notch and make custom fields a breeze
http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/